# Nth Value of Fibonacci Sequence JavaScript (timeout error)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, while-loop, fibonacci

I have a working solution for this Kata (find nth value of Fibonacci Sequence), however I keep getting a timeout error.  Can anyone offer advice on how to refactor this to run more efficiently?  Thanks in advance!

Here is the link with description - https://www.codewars.com/kata/simple-fun-number-395-fibonacci-digit-sequence/train/javascript

> You are given three non negative integers a, b and n, and making an infinite sequence just like fibonacci sequence, use the following rules:
>
> step1: use ab as the initial sequence. 
>   step2: calculate the sum of the
>   last two digits of the sequence, and append it to the end of sequence.
>   repeat step2 
>   Your task is to complete function find. 
>   Return nth digit(0-based) of the sequence.

```js
function find(a,b,n){
  let start = ("" + a + b);
  let next = a + b;
  let seq = start + next;
  
  while (seq.length <= n) {
    seq += (parseInt(seq[seq.length-2]) + parseInt(seq[seq.length-1]));
  }
  return parseInt(seq[n]);
}

console.log(find(7,8,9))

// should return 5
```

Comment: Here is the Codewars link - https://www.codewars.com/kata/simple-fun-number-395-fibonacci-digit-sequence/train/javascript

Comment: `function find(a,b,n) { return 5; }`?

Comment: Not sure about the speed, but your answer is only correct by coincidence. You need to `parseInt` each string individually. You code continually adds `15` to the end of the string.

Comment: @MarkMeyer You're absolutely right - code has been edited to reflect that change.  However, I tried it before with parseInt on each string and logged each iteration to the console and while the output was correct, I was still receiving the timeout error.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Please add a description of the problem to the question, not just a link in the comments.

Comment: @Barmar Done, thanks!

Comment: @JustinCefai: You've misunderstood Barmar's comment. (S)he's not saying to add the *link*, (s)he's saying to add the *description*. Your question should continue to make sense long after codewars.com has disappeared or become infested with malware.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly . . . don't use strings, don't use `parseInt`, don't hold onto the entire sequence at once. You only need numbers, and you only need the last two digits. Given a number `x` between 10 and 18 (which is the largest possible sum of two digits), its tens' place is `1` and its ones' place is `x - 10`. That alone will be a significant improvement.

Secondly . . . since the entire sequence after a given point is determined by the first two digits at that point,<sup>1</sup> and there are only 100 possible sequences of two digits, every sequence has to repeat within 200 digits; that is, within at most 200 digits, it will necessarily enter a loop of repeating digits that it never gets out of, where that loop is less than 200 digits long.<sup>2</sup> So if `n` is greater than a few hundred, you can massively optimize by finding the length of this loop and "skipping" a large multiple of that length.

<sub>1. Actually, this isn't quite true as written. For example, the sequences 69156… and 79167… bot contain 91, but followed by different things. This is because the '1' belongs to a two-digit number, *both* of whose digits are determined by the previous two digits. I'm not sure how to express this better, but hopefully you see what I mean. It doesn't affect the overall argument, but it's something you need to be careful with in how you apply the idea.</sub>
<sub>2. Actually much less; testing all possible values of *a* and *b*, I find that the sequence always enters the loop *and* completes its first iteration within just 25 digits! But I'm not sure how to rigorously justify this much smaller figure other than exhaustive testing; so it would probably be cheating to write the code in a way that relied on it.</sub>

Comment: thanks for the response!  In regards to "don't hold on to the entire sequence at once" - how would you find an element at the nth position if you're not keeping track of the length?

Comment: @JustinCefai: One option is to keep a `position` variable, and you're done when `position` reaches `n`. Another option is to decrease `n` as you progress through the sequence, and you're done when `n` reaches `0`. (N.B. in both cases, you need to be careful to handle two-digit numbers correctly.)

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you get the tens place with `(x - x % 10) / 10` I think that gives you the number truncated to it's tens digit and one more `% 10` is required.

Comment: @MarkMeyer: Since it's a two-digit number, there's literally no difference between "the tens place" and "the number truncated to it's tens digit". An extra `% 10` is harmless but unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

When you are converting and doing string operation it is generally slower.

```
function nextVal(num){
    const last = (num%10);
    const lastButOne = (num - last)/10 % 10;
    const sum = last + lastButOne;
    return sum < 10 ? num * 10 + sum : num *100 + sum;
}
function find(a,b,n){
  let num = a * 10 + b;
  const above = Math.pow(10, n);// anything less than we don't have enough digits


  while (num < above) {
    num = nextVal(num);
  }
  return Number(`${num}`.charAt(n));
}
```

The above code relies on number checking and only converts it into string (which can also be avoided)